# Javascript convert canvas to img

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, html5-canvas

I am using cropper js to crop images.
more info at: https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropperjs

so this is my javascript code to get cropped picture as canvas

```
var result = document.getElementById('result');
result.innerHTML = '';
result.appendChild(cropper.getCroppedCanvas());
```

Result div:

```
<div id="result"></div>
```

after cropped it returns to me canvas inside result div

```
<div id="result"> <canvas width="137" height="137"></canvas></div>
```

My question is how to return as `<img src=""></img>`  instead of `<canvas>` tag ?

Comment: How would you do? I need as img because i have some scripts that animate the img element.

Comment: So maybe the best solution would handle image on backend and get as Ajax response?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var image = new Image();
image.id = "pic"
image.src = cropper.getCroppedCanvas().toDataURL();
document.getElementById('image_for_crop').appendChild(image);
```

Comment: Dang. 40s late.

Comment: Cool, I am on phone now, I Will test latter and see How It goes.

Comment: Very nice and simple solution, Thanks!

Comment: Now I am trying to add a class to image, some how not working to add the class 
`var image = new Image();
image.class="img-fluid w-100"
image.id = "pic"
image.src = cropper.getCroppedCanvas().toDataURL();
document.getElementById('result').appendChild(image);`